# Reduce an Array of Objects With Duplicate IDs by a Second Date Property

Tags: javascript, arrayobject

I have an array of objects and all of them have at least 1 other object with the same ID. I am trying to reduce this array to only return the object with the most recent date. An example array of what I'm dealing with:

```
var arrObj = [
   {id: 1, startDate: 2019-10-09},
   {id: 1, startDate: 2019-10-05},
   {id: 1, startDate: 2019-09-30},
   {id: 2, startDate: 2018-08-05},
   {id: 2, startDate: 2018-09-05}
]
```

Output I am trying to achieve:

```
var newArrObj = [
   {id: 1, startDate: 2019-10-09},
   {id: 2, startDate: 2018-09-05}
]
```

I have found a lot of examples of reducing or removing duplicate objects by ID completely, but I can't seem to find an example of first identifying the objects with the same ID, then reducing by a second property. Unfortunately I keep finding myself creating a lot of nested for loops. Is there an elegant way to do this? I need to be able to do it in ES5 or earlier.

```
var uniqueIDs = [];
for (a in arrObj) {
  if(uniqueIDs.indexOf(arrObj[a].id) != -1) {
     uniqueIDs.push(arrObj[a].id);
  }
}

var newArrObj = [];
for(b in uniqueIDs) {
  var uniqueId = uniqueIDs[b];
  var uniqueIdObjs = arrObj.filter(function(x) {
    return x.id === uniqueId;
  });
  for(c in uniqueIdObjs) {
    var objDate = uniqueIdObjs[c].startDate;
    //This is where I get stuck
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with your style of first filtering the IDs to uniques, because thats the easy part.
Then you can simply chain array function so extract the last date:

1. map over the unique IDs so that your returns create a new array at the end.
2. filter the original array to include only object with the ID we workin on now
3. sort the temporary array created with all objects of the same ID so that the mostrecent one would be first, and return the first element.

   ```
   let finalResult = uniqueIDs.map( id => {
      return arrayObj.filter( obj => obj.id === id )
       .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate))[0];
   ```

Tada! `finalResult` is now and array containing only one object with the most recent date for every ID :)

Comment: I really like this answer Gibor! I am trying to do this without arrow functions if possible and am getting a syntax error with this:   var finalResult = uniqueIDs.map(function(id) {
   return arrObj.filter( function(obj){ obj.id === id })
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate))[0]
    })

Comment: it would help if I knew what syntax error you're getting haha. This seems ok to me. And as a best practice i'd suggest using `let` instead of `var`, just a side note :) @MattMcCode

Comment: and also- why without arrow functions? Doesn't make much sense, although its not supposed to effect in this case

Comment: Unfortunately I have to script in Google Apps Script and they are a little limited in certain JS features. One being not accepting arrow functions :(. It's a little behind the times, so sometimes hard to dumb down newer JS examples. The error reporting is also lacking, I just get "Syntax Error" line 33. And they don't support 'Let' yet. Not ideal I know!

Comment: I was actually able to manipulate your answer a bit to make it work for me! check it out:   var newArray = [];
  for(b in uniqueIDs) {
    var uniqueId = uniqueIDs[b];
    var matchedObjs = arrObj.filter(function(x) {
      return x.id === uniqueId;
    });
    matchedObjs = matchedObjs.sort(function(a,b) {
      return new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate)
    })
    newArray.push(matchedObjs[0])
  }

Comment: Oh lol I see... My guess it is the `forEach` that caused the problem with the syntax error, u might still be able to do it in one statement inside the `for`. Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array by date, get an array of `id`s and dedupe it, then `map` the deduped array to replace them with actual objects from the sorted array, `Array.find` will return the first matching result :

```js
var arrObj = [
  { id: 1, startDate: "2019-10-09" },
  { id: 1, startDate: "2019-10-05" },
  { id: 1, startDate: "2019-09-30" },
  { id: 2, startDate: "2018-08-05" },
  { id: 2, startDate: "2018-09-05" }
];

// Sort by date
var sorted = arrObj.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate));

// dedupe the array of ids
var ids = [...new Set(sorted.map(o => o.id))];

// replace the ids with original objects
var result = ids.map(id => sorted.find(o => o.id === id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers rely on iterating through your data multiple times, which is *fine* over a small data set, but the larger your data set, the performance will degrade by a factor of the number of times you loop through your data.  The accepted answer is especially bad because you'll be scanning your entire array for each unique ID.  If you have 1000 unique IDs, that's 1000 full scans of your array (yikes).

Since your goal is to get the latest item from the arrObj, deduped by ID, object functions operate much faster than array functions.

```
const collection = {};
arrObj.forEach(obj => {
  if(!collection[obj.id] || collection[obj.id].date < obj.date) //might need to convert to actual dates and do getTime() on them
  {
    collection[obj.id] = obj;
  }
});
const latestEntries = Object.values(collection)
```

this way, no matter how large or unique your data set is, you're only ever looping through your entire collection twice (once in the `forEach`, and at the end when you do `Object.values(collection)`